# Text files help(Python 3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Students.txt

```
64 Mary Ryan
89 Michael Murphy
22 Pepe
78 Jenny Smith
57 Patrick James McMahon
89 John Kelly
22 Pepe
74 John C. Reilly
```

My code

```
f = open("students.txt","r")
for line in f:
    words = line.strip().split()
    mark = (words[0])
    name = " ".join(words[1:])
    for i in (mark):
        print(i)
```

The output im getting is

```
6
4
8
9
2
2
7
8
etc...
```

My expected output is

64
80
22
78
etc..

Just curious to know how I would print the whole integer, not just a single integer at a time.

Any help would be more than appreciative.

Comment: Replace `words[1:]` with `words[2:]`.

Comment: `for line in f:words = line.strip().split()` should be written on two lines

Comment: Try `(words[:2])name`.

Answer (score 0):

in your line:

```
line.strip().split()
```

you're not telling the sting to split based on a space. Try the following:

```
str(line).strip().split(" ")
```

Comment: I believe space is the default when no arguments are supplied.

Comment: Okay I done line.strip().split(" ") but hasnt helped

Comment: added string coercion to the 'line' to allow for numerics

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have some integer with a string in the text file. You wanted to know about your code will output only full Integer.

**You can use the code**

```
f = open("Students.txt","r")
for line in f:
    l = line.split(" ")
    print(l[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, when you do this:

```
for i in (mark):
  print(i)
```

and `mark` is of type `string`, you are asking Python to iterate over each *character* in the string.  So, if your string contains space-separated integers and you iterate over the string, you'll get one integer at a time.

I believe in your code the line

```
 mark = (words[0])name = " ".join(words[1:])
```

is a typo.  If you fix that we can help you with what's missing (it's most likely a statement like `mark = something.split()`, but not sure what `something` is based on the code).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using context managers when you open files so that they are automatically closed for you when the scope ends. Also `mark` should be a list to which you append the first element of the line split. All together it will look like this:

```
with open("students.txt","r") as f:
    mark = []
    for line in f:
        mark.append(line.strip().split()[0])
for i in mark:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
for i in (mark):
```

is same as this because `mark` is a string:

```
for i in mark:
```

I believe you want to make `mark` an element of some iterable, which you can create a tuple with single item by:

```
for i in (mark,):
```

and this should give what you want.

Comment: Hi thanks that works , but I dont understand how that works

Comment: e.g. `(1)` is a number `1` and `('hello')` is a string `'hello'` which the bracket is optional. However, `(1,)` and `('hello',)` are tuples and the brakcets and commas are significant here. In your case, you want to loop through a one-element iterable. Therefore you do not want to present `mark` as a string but use `(mark,)` as a one-element tuple instead. Otherwise you're looping through all characters in the string `mark`

Answer (score 0):

A quick one with list comprehensions:

```
with open("students.txt","r") as f:    
    mark = [line.strip().split()[0] for line in f]
for i in mark:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you , Im bit rusty on list comprehensions but thats a nice way to do it